# Example of Maxwell Equations with 24 boundary conditions

Tags: maxwell-equations

In Christopher Bairds [supplementary notes](https://www.wtamu.edu/%7Ecbaird/SuppMaxwellUniqueness.pdf) on the Uniqueness of Maxwell Equations, he says that in full generality one needs 24 boundary conditions to uniquely determine a solution of Maxwells equations. However, I have never actually seen a problem requiring 24 conditions. Are there are any simple examples where one can clearly see this?

Comment: I could count up to 10, not sure if the other are some smooth derivative conditions or something like that...